# How to delete a client-side cookie when I access a certain page?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion

I am trying to delete a client-side cookie when I access a certain page. How to I do this? Even after using the code below, I'm unable to delete the client side cookie:

```
<cfcookie name="GIFT CAT" value="" expires="NOW" />
<cfset StructDelete(cookie, 'GIFTCAT', false)>
```

Comment: What test are you using to verify the cookie was deleted *and on what page*? You cannot do this in a single request. The http response must be sent back to the browser for the client cookie to actually be deleted. That change will be reflected in the next http request.

Comment: i have tested in browser level as well as keeping <cddump var=""#cookie#>...when i tested through browser level cookie is still showing...but when i keep the dump to see the result showing empty string

Comment: (Edit) *Where* are you doing the dumps? That would happen if you are trying to delete the cookie and dump the cookie scope in the same request. Like I mentioned, you cannot do that. You you must delete the cookie in one request - then check the status in the *next* http request.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i m clear with my problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure all attributes are the same as on the set cookie. So secure, domain and path specifically.

```
<cfcookie name="test1" value="1" domain="test.com" />
<cfcookie name="test1" value="" expires="now" />
```

doesn't work, but

```
<cfcookie name="test1" value="1" domain="test.com" />
<cfcookie name="test1" value="" domain="test.com" expires="now" />
```

does work.

Comment: True, but I do not think that is the problem here. I think "gift cat" versus "giftcat" is just a typo. If that were their actual code, it would not even compile because `cfcookie` does not allow spaces in cookie names.

Comment: I totally read over the actual differences in Naresh's code, I just figured this is what usually is wrong when a cookie won't delete.

Comment: Yep. That is definitely high on the "most common cookie mistakes" list along with deleting and verifying in the same request. So chances are it is one of the two :)

Answer (score 2):

(Expanded from comments)

It sounds like you are testing the cookie status incorrectly. You cannot do this in a single http request. The http response must be sent back to the browser for the client cookie to actually be deleted. That change will be reflected in the *next* http request.

> when i keep the dump to see the result showing empty string

Also, if you review the ColdFusion documentation it states that `expire="now"` **does not delete the corresponding variable [from] the Cookie scope of the active page**). So if you delete a cookie, then dump the `cookie` scope on the same page, the deleted cookie will still exist. In your case the `value` will be an empty string.

Properly testing the behavior requires three requests:

1. Create the cookie:
   `<cfcookie name="GIFT_CAT" value="Created cookie at #now()#"/>`. After running the script in your browser, "GIFT_CAT":

   - Exists in the CF `cookie` scope
   - Exists in browser cookies
2. Delete the cookie: `<cfcookie name="GIFT_CAT" value="" expires="NOW" />`. After running the script in your browser, "GIFT_CAT":

   - Still exists in the CF `cookie` scope (because `expire` does not delete it on the active page)
   - Does NOT exist in browser cookies (because the browser deletes the cookie after receiving the response)
3. Finally, verify the cookies: `<cfdump var="#COOKIE#">`. After running the script in your browser, "GIFT_CAT":

   - Does NOT exist in the CF `cookie` scope
   - Does NOT exist in browser cookies